# jQuery - Why does $('form').get(0).submit() not trigger the attached submit handler?

Tags: jquery, forms

Suppose I've created the following handler (callback) for a form:

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert('form submitted');
});
```

Why does calling `$('form').get(0).submit` not call the submit handler? The form just gets directly submitted.

Answer (score 3):

`.get(0)` returns the native js DOM element ( Same as `$('form')[0]` ) and then you are triggering the 
submit event directly.

if you are trying to get the first Element use `.eq(0)` and trigger the submit jQuery style using `.submit()`.

**Summary**:

- `$('selector')[0]` ~ returns the native js DOM element
- `.get(0)` ~ Same as [0].
- `.eq(0)` ~ returns the first element as a jQuery object .

**More**:

- Attach to submit event (jQuery): `$('form.selector').submit(function (e) { });`
- Trigger Submit (jQuery): `$('form.selector').submit();` OR `$('form.selector').trigger('submit');`
- Trigger Submit on the first element:  `$('form').eq(0).submit();`

**Demo**: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/edeeqoy3/)

I hope its what you need.

*Demo jQuery*:

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Will prevent the native handler from firing.
    alert('form submitted :' + $(this).attr("id"));
});

//change the `.eq(index)` to 1 to trigger the submit on the second form:  
$('form').eq(0).submit(); // Same as: $('form').eq(0).trigger("submit");
```

*Demo HTML*:

```
<form id="form1"></form>
<form id="form2"></form>
```

Comment: Wow, this is new - so there are two handlers for submit? One bound to native DOM elements, and one bound to jQuery object? Is there a way to bind a callback to native DOM element _AND_ jQuery object?

Comment: @bodacydo that's not so true - Only one submit event handler (JS) - jQuery submit() will trigger it when its done unless you add the `event.preventDefault();` that will prevent the actual event to be called.

Comment: but as you can see, calling $('form').get(0).submit() does not call the jquery's trigger... so there must be another trigger just for the DOM element? Am i wrong?

Comment: .submit() is a jQuery method and doesn't exist in the native object ( that get(0) returns ), .submit() can be called on a jQuery element and will trigger the js .submit + the handler you assigned.